# How to plot how variables change in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

oes anyone know a way to plot how a watched variable changes over time in Visual Studio 2010?  I.e. if you had the following code

```
double someVariable;
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    someVariable = Math.Pi() * i;
}
```

and you watched 'someVariable' in the ide you could step through the code and watch how it grows with each step.  I would like to be able to run through the loop and plot what that variable did with out having to manually step through it.  I am doing a lot of math and sometimes watching how variables change is really useful and insightful.

More info:
I have a bunch of slightly different solvers and depending on the problem I am troubleshooting I would like to watch different variables to see where the problems are occurring.  I currently put log these variables to a log file but it slows down the solver significantly and I have to spend a decent amount of time changing debug code to track down problems.  I am looking for a slicker way to do this that is IDE centric.  Sort of a Visualizer on steroids.

Comment: Can you just output it to the console? `Console.WriteLine()` or `Trace.WriteLine()`

Comment: This is perfect for a Perfmon counter/variable - see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using Tracepoints? In VS 2008 (it's somewhat different in VS 2010) you just add a normal breakpoint, then right-click on it, then select "When Hit...".

In the subsequent dialog box, check "Print a message" and enter something like

```
someVariable = {someVariable}
```

This will just output its value to the output window in the IDE.

Screenshot:

[image: tracepoint dialog]

Comment: This is certainly along the lines of what I am trying to accomplish.  But when I tried it I couldn't find where it was printing to.

Comment: Never mind, I found it in the output where it makes the most sense.  This is a great tip!!

Answer (score 1):

Easy way? None.

But you can code it yourself..

1. Use property.
2. In setter put code, that will log change in some collection. Possibly save time too.
3. Use some plotting control to plot this collection

Edit:
If you dont want to create property, you can create some kind of generic class, that will have this property and has some kind of internal logging logic.

Comment: This is pretty much what I do now, except I use my built in logging code to log it to my log file.  The problem with this is that it costs speed and some times I forget to take it out.  The other problem is that I have dozens of slightly different solvers in my project and would like something that is IDE centric instead of code specific so when I need the functionality it is there but when I don't it isn't deployed to my users slowing down their software.

Comment: I'm not the best person to address this, but I think you may be able to use your web.config to build it differently for production than what you run in debug mode. This way, you wouldn't need to remember to remove this for your build. Hopefully someone else can verify and possibly explain this better.

Comment: One other trick that may help is to put //***DEBUG*** after each line you want to remove or comment for your buid.  Then do a project search for that so you can quickly find all the lines.

Comment: This is important information. You should put it in your original question.

Comment: It is a desktop app, but you are right I could use debug code to not deploy it, but that doesn't solve my problem of having to code it in each of my solvers and coming up with a fairly big hammer for a problem that I would like a smaller more agile tool to quickly look at any variable and not have to change my code.

Comment: Euphoric- You are correct about it being important info.  I have edited the main question to add the info.  It was an oversight on my part to over simplify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Perfmon and publish that value to a counter that perfmon can read.  Perfmon does all the plotting etc.  You just need to publish to perfmon.  Unfrotunately it is not very well documented and is not trivial. (well, at least it wasn't trivial for unmanaged c++ when I was looking into it)

I did this a while back and used some classes published in an **old** MSJ article.  (ca 1998 or so)

I will try to find some online docs.

[See this question for some links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885069/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-publishing-data-to-perfmon-in-c)

[This may also be useful](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/how-do-i-publish-a-custom-application-performance-counter-in-c/645)

If you find a solution or this works for you please let us know.

Comment: This is certainly interesting but is probably a lot more involved than I really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone will come up with a better answer, but here is what I did in a similar situation...

I output the values, in CSV format, to the console.  From there, I would copy and paste into Excel, and let Excel do some graphing for me.  It worked quite well, but was a complete hassle during a caffeine-driven development session.

Comment: I currently log it to a log file, see above response as to why I am looking for a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define and array and write someVariable to array[i] inside the loop?  Then you could reference it after you're done.

```
double[] x = new double[20];
double someVariable; 
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
     someVariable = Math.Pi() * i;
     x[i] = someVariable;
}
```

Comment: I have dozens of solvers in my code that I would prefer to have a single solution for instead of implementing a solution in each solver, and I am trying to keep the solvers as light and fast as possible and don't want to deploy anything to my users.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [SpPerfChart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17564/Simple-Performance-Chart) very easy to use and helpful. Simply add the user control and input your changing data to it. You'll get a graphical plot of whatever number you input realtime.